# Animated div animates upwards on route change

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am using framer-motion to handle some simple animation effects whenever my horizontal navigation bar buttons are pressed. It looks something like the following, in this case `<ul>` is a `position: sticky` element.

```
<ul className="sticky">
  <li className="relative text-base  font-normal text-gray-400">
    {activePath === '/' ? (
      <motion.div
        className="absolute left-0   top-0 right-0  h-full w-full items-center gap-x-2  rounded-md"
        layoutId="underline"
        key={activePath}
      />
    ) : null}
    <Link href="/" aria-label="Home" type="button">
      Home
    </Link>
  </li>

  <li className="relative text-base  font-normal text-gray-400">
    {activePath === '/about' ? (
      <motion.div
        className="absolute left-0  top-0 right-0  h-full w-full items-center gap-x-2  rounded-md"
        layoutId="underline"
        key={activePath}
      />
    ) : null}
    <Link href="/about" aria-label="About" type="button">
      About
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These animations work great when I'm at the top of the page, however whenever my `Link` is pressed and I'm further down the page, my animated divs end up animating to the top of the page as a route click causes a scrollTop event to occur. You can see them animating from the bottom back to the desired position at the top, I assume because the `<ul>` element is jumping to the top of the page, and the animations have a degree of transition time.

I would like it so my animations only occur on the X axis as opposed to the Y axis, but it seems like it needs a second to catch up to the updated placement of the `<ul>` element. Is there a way to handle this  without forcing my entire component to update?

The [closest example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/framer-motion-layout-animations-snxgv?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx&from-embed=) of what I'm doing is here on the framer-motion site.

Comment: The solution for me was to add `style={{ originY: '0px' }}` to the animated div.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick!